# Getting "(sensitive value)" from `terraform state show`, how can I uncensor the value?

Tags: terraform

When I run I try to use [`terraform state show`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/state/show) on [variables flagged sensitive](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/configuration-language/sensitive-variables) on some addresses I get

```
private_data = (sensitive value)
```

How can I get around this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately you can not. There is already a filed issue on this [#32439](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/32439).

## Workaround

Until that's resolved you'll have to use

```
terraform show -json | jq QUERY
```

And learn how to query with jq to get what you want.

Comment: This was helpful! thanks for sharing!